# Quantitative Analysis

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Please help me out with this. Not getting any approach to solve this.

Let 'k' be a +ve integer such that k+4 is divisible by 7. Then the smallest +ve integer 'n' , greater than 2, such that k+2n is divisible by 7 equals :

PS: I am confused b/w "perfectly divisible" and "divisible" rather in this case because I did a question from my same text book which is previous to this one being asked. It said "perfectly divisible". Although the question was different from this one yet I got this feeling that in "perfectly divisible" you get no remainder so is this case a different one or both the statements are used "interchangeably"

May be I am leaving out some mere details or some basic maths but its okay...often we do mistakes...so please solve this with a better explanation of the concept and especially the PS section. Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: What's a "+ve integer"?

Comment: @fleablood Lol, that stands for "positive". It comes as "positive-integer".

Comment: Anyway, the answer is the same as asking what is the smallest $n>2$ such that $2(n-2)$ is divisible by $7$. And this is $n=9$.

Comment: @Crostul Yes bro, your answer is correct. Can you elaborate it, I mean how did you break it?

Answer (score 0):

$k + 4 = m7$ for some integer $m$.

$k + 2n = j7$ for some integer $j$.

Solve for $n$.

$2n = j7 - k = j7 - m7+4 = (j-m)7 + 4$

$n = \frac{j-m}{2}7 + 2$

what is the smallest such positive number greater than 2.  Clearly $n =9$

Then $k + 2n = k+4$ is divisible by 7.

If you are familiar with modular notation.

$k + 4 \equiv 0 \mod 7 \iff k \equiv -4 \equiv 3 \mod 7$.

$k + 2n \equiv 2n + 3 \mod 7 \equiv 0$

$2n \equiv -3 \equiv 4 \mod 7$

$n \equiv 2 \mod 7 \equiv 2 +7 = 9 \mod 7$.

Smallest such positive $n>2$ is $9$.

====

"perfectly divisible" and "divisible" probably doesn't mean anything different.  "divisible" *implies* divisible by an integer with an integer result with no remainder.  "perfectly divisible" is probably simply used to rules out non-integer results.

Comment: Correct answer is '9' buddy.

Comment: Oh, you're right.  I didn't see the n > 2 requirement.

Comment: Same thing though.  n = 2 is smallest positive integer.  Just add 7 to get the next one.

Comment: Yo..thanx bro..I really appreciate it. I think there's no need for modular notation though...Well thanx once again..:)

Comment: Well, modular notation, once you know it, is usually considered *easier* and more basic than $k + 4 = 7m$.  We don't give a flip about m or j or (m-j) or the restriction that (m-j) is even so why should we bother writing them?  Modular arithmetic is *much* cleaner.  $k + 4 = 0 (mod 7)$.  End of story.